# How to precompile a file after filtering?

Tags: maven

I am building a .war file which contains a .jsp file. In the .jsp, there is some maven property variables, thus I need to filter it by using maven war plugin. 
Besides that, I would like to precompile it, using mojo jspc plugin, and pack the .class file into the war file.

However, the filtered file is not compiled. The result war file consists the filtered .jsp file and the non filtered .class file.

How should I configure the pom.xml in order to compile the filtered .jsp?

My pom file is shown below:

```
  <build>
<finalName>${Component}</finalName>
<resources>
    <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
    </resource>
</resources>
<plugins> 
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <archiveClasses>true</archiveClasses>  
      <attachClasses>true</attachClasses> 
      <packagingExcludes>**/*.vpp,WEB-INF/web.xml,**/eclipselink.jar,**/coherence.jar,**  /toplink-grid.jar</packagingExcludes>
      <outputFileNameMapping>@{artifactId}@.@{extension}@</outputFileNameMapping> 
      <webResources>
        <resource>
          <directory>src/main/webapp/verification</directory>
          <targetPath>verification</targetPath> 
          <filtering>true</filtering> 
        </resource>
      </webResources>  
      <executions>
          <execution>
              <phase>process-resources</phase> 
          </execution>
      </executions>         
    </configuration>
  </plugin>



  <!-- start jspc -->

  <plugin>
     <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
     <artifactId>jspc-maven-plugin</artifactId>
     <executions>
         <execution>
             <id>jspc</id>           
             <goals>        
                 <goal>compile</goal>
             </goals>             
              <phase>compile</phase> 
         </execution>
     </executions>
 </plugin>
  <!-- end jspc -->

</plugins>
</build>
```

The JSP file is stored in src/main/webapp/verification

Answer (score 0):

It is very probable that the plugins execute in the wrong order. Most plugins allow to change the phase they bind to, by adding e.g. `<phase>generate-resources</phase>`.  You need to explicitly bind the plugins to phases in such way to execute the filtering first. Phases are documented [here](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html). Choose the appropriate ones to bind to.
Btw, filtering JSPs directly is a pretty bad practice. Instead, generate a .properties file (filter it, or generate dynamically) and load it to Servlet context, so it's available to all JSPs. If you using Spring, this is a breeze. Example below (runtime.properties is the filtered/generated file):

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextAttributeExporter">
        <property name="attributes">
            <map>
                <entry key="config">
                    <util:properties location="classpath:runtime.properties"/>
                </entry>
            </map>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

You then access it in JSPs as `config['someKey']`. This also eliminated the need to worry about the phase JSPs get filtered.

Comment: or can i guide the jspc plugin to precompile the filtered jsp in target file  ?

Comment: Yes, that would probably work too. The goal is only to get the two steps to execute in the correct order on the correct files. I still hold the best option would be to not filter JSPs directly at all, though.